# `gnome-screenshot`: How to increase the maximum of a screenshot

Tags: debian, lxde, screenshot

I'm working on the latest `Debian Buster LXDE` on a `1920x1080` screen without any DPI scaling. I'm using a bash script to take screenshots by screen, window or area.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case "${1}" in
    "-a" | "--area" )
        gnome-screenshot --area --clipboard
        ;;
    "-c" | "--complete" )
        gnome-screenshot --clipboard
        ;;
    "-w" | "--window" )
        gnome-screenshot --window --clipboard
        ;;
    "-h" | "--help" | * )
        echo "Usage: take-screenshot [OPTION]"
        echo
        echo "Options:"
        echo
        echo -e "  -h, --help\t\tShows the help."
        echo -e "  -a, --area\t\tTakes a screenshot of a selected area."
        echo -e "  -c, --complete\tTakes a screenshot across all screens."
        echo -e "  -w, --window\t\tTakes a screenshot of the active window."
        ;;
esac
```

Some time ago I discovered I cannot take screenshots by display or window but by area anymore. Today I discovered I cannot take a screenshot by area either.

While trying to insert the copied image anywhere there's some long loading time and nothing happens.

After some tries today I experienced there's a maximum size of a screenshot. Smaller areas or windows are still able to take a screenshot of. I didn't try to figure out the maximum boundaries.

1. How can I increase the maximun size of a screenshot? There's no documented option of `gnome-screenshot`.
2. While at least in `Debian Stretch LXDE` I was able to take all three kinds of a screenshot maybe there's a bug in `Debian Buster LXDE` now?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/-/issues/110

Comment: @IporSircer I can't see any relation to my issue except you want to point out a DBUS relation I'm not familiar with. (I'm not familiar with DBUS at all.)